# 1 million records for Opportunity and it has Amount field, need to calculate the total opportunity Amount at end of every day and send in email

Tags: apex, batch

I have scheduled a Batch that will fetch opportunity values and in a static variable, it will store and keep adding them and at the end of the batch and at the finish I am sending the value via email. (the commutative value).   Let suppose during the batch execution someone changed the value of some record.

How can we handle this scenario to get the latest value?

Comment: Do you even need code, is a scheduled report an option?

Comment: Thank you for the response, but it's an existing functionality with some logic and the customer reported a bug and we have to provide the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Batch execution vs user updating an opportunity record are 2 different transactions, each executing within its own limits and boundaries. From a synchronous transaction, you are trying see how to signal recalculation/ adjudication need to an asynchronous transaction. AFAIK, this is not possible in apex (*although you could come up with workaround solutions, they may not be foolproof*).

Looks like you are processing large number of records during business hours (*or at the least having some overlap with the business hours*), there by providing a window for user to update an opportunity record. As long as you have higher execution time for the batch apex, you are providing large window for user updates and any logic that you would try to fix the bug will not be fool proof (*think about the chances of user updating an opportunity record during the batch finish method execution, although minimal*). Also, I'm assuming that your code is processing the same opportunity records everyday, which is not a good design IMO. You should possibly perform a one-time calculation of the total opportunity amount during non-business hours, store it somewhere and consider processing only updated opportunities on a daily basis. This is, of course, if you are unable to resort to scheduled reporting due to business requirement.

Comment: thanks for the response, yes for now we have provided the same solution which you have given.